# CakePHP 3 hasMany update strange behaviour

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have  JobsTable:

This is relation definition:

```
$this->hasMany( 'JobContracts', [ 
  'foreignKey' => 'job_id' 
] );
```

Saving code:

```
$entity = $this->patchEntity( $entity, $toSave, [
        'fieldList' => ['notes],
        'associated' => [ 
            'JobContracts' => ['fieldList' => ['id', 'checked']]
        ] 
    ] );
```

And now:
if I put this notes in fieldList then JobContracts are NOT saved properly.
If I remove fieldList, then I am able to save it properly.

Question is Why? I need to control base model fields also. Any suggestions?

Ive already checked: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#avoiding-property-mass-assignment-attacks

Comment: Please try to avoid descriptions like "not saved properly", that could mean absolutely anything, and in the world of programming it's all about being exact. Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow assigning the association property too, not only `notes`. If you don't, then the associated data is never going to be set on the resulting entity, and consequently is not going to be saved.

Check the docs that you've linked again, the tags example shows exactly that:

> ```
> // Only allow changing the title and tags
> // and the tag name is the only column that can be set
> $entity = $this->patchEntity($entity, $data, [
>     'fieldList' => ['title', 'tags'],
>     'associated' => ['Tags' => ['fieldList' => ['name']]]
> ]);
> $this->save($entity);
> ```

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#avoiding-property-mass-assignment-attacks**

So, add `job_contracts` to the field list, and you should be good.